# Definir nome para uma Foreign Key criada a partir de uma Migration no Laravel

Tags: laravel

Estou construindo uma aplicação utilizando o Laravel 5.1 e no meu Diagrama ER ele é bem profundo e detalhado (até com a nomenclatura de índexes). Preciso saber como posso fazer para criar uma Foreign Key utilizando os métodos de migration do laravel em que eu possa definir o nome da mesma, talvez algo do tipo:

```
Schema::create('historico', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->dateTime('data_reg')
          ->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
    $table->integer('usuario_id');
    $table->foreign('usuario_id')
          ->foreignName('historico$usuario_id') // <-- procuro isso aqui
          ->references('id')
          ->on('usuario')
          ->onDelete('CASCADE')
          ->onUpdate('CASCADE');
    $table->string('acao', 500);
    $table->longText('conteudo')->nullable();
});
```

Comment: Se a resposta resolveu o problema, considere por gentileza marcá-la. Assim saberemos que ela foi útil para você e terá uma melhor visualização por parte do outros usuário.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passe um segundo parâmetro na função foreign().
Exemplo:

```
$table->foreign('usuario_id', 'nome_da_foreign_key') // o que você procura
          ->references('id')
          ->on('usuario')
          ->onDelete('CASCADE')
          ->onUpdate('CASCADE');
```

Você pode ver o prototipo da função foreign key no arquivo Blueprint.php do laravel:

```
/**
     * Specify a foreign key for the table.
     *
     * @param  string|array  $columns
     * @param  string  $name
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Fluent
     */
    public function foreign($columns, $name = null)
    {
        return $this->indexCommand('foreign', $columns, $name);
    }
```